# i am getting this error File "Solution.py", line 3, in <module> o=int(input()) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3 1000'

Tags: python

i got this error ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3 1000' although i got right answer in jupyternotebook but hackerrank is throwing thi error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKPqV.png)

```
enter # Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
nlst=[]
o=int(input())
nlst.append(o)
t=nlst[0]
nlst.append[10**t]
b=0
for x in range(nlst[0]):
     z=int(input())
     lname='list'+str(nlst[0])
     for y in range(z):
         lname=[]
         lname.append(int(input()))
    a= sorted(lname)
    b=b+a[-1]**2    
output=b%max1
print(output)code here`
```

Comment: Well, what number do you expect `3 1000` to be?

Comment: The error tells you the exact problem, your input is `'3 1000'` (note the space) and you can't make an `int` out of that